# Как передать cookies при создании websocket соединения?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

Я на стороне клиента создаю websocket соединение.

```
let socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost");
```

На сервере принимается соединение.

Сервер express Node.js

```
webSocketServer.on("connection", async (ws) => {

ws.id = ????
})
```

Как я с клиента могу передать id который хочу использовать для создания websocket соединения ?